# How do you open or view the contents of .ch3 files?

Tags: file-extension

We have some Harvard Graphics containing documentation from a legacy system.

How can I open or view the contents of these .ch3 files? Or has the file format gone past deprecation?

Comment: Yeesh, Harvard Graphics is still advertising the version for Windows 95/98/ME.  I wonder if there's a viewer...

Comment: There is a viewer but it only opens .pr4 files, which (to my understanding) are complete presentations, while ch3 files are single graphics and charts.

Comment: I just did some digging but I couldn't find squat.  If you can dig up a copy of Windows 98, there's always the virtual machine approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old versions of Office (PowerPoint specifically) had a CH3 import filter.  I'm pretty sure this was available in Office 97, not sure how long it hung around in later versions.  If installing an older copy of Office is practical, post back; I've got various versions installed and can check for you to see which includes the CH3 filter.

Or if it's just a couple of files, I could try opening and converting them for you.

Comment: A colleague of mine was able to open the files with Powerpoint 2002. Thanks a lot for the help!